# My code has some data leakage/invalid access issues

Tags: c, linked-list, file-writing

The input file has the integers : 3 5 2 9 
The linked list works and the insert method sorts the data properly
I simply can't figure out why this is showing up.
I have freed the pointer values and I have closed the opened files. I'm not very familiar
with using C so I'm guessing it has to do with a misplaced pointer value? Any help would be appreciated.

the error message is as follows:

```
======= Backtrace: =========
/lib/i686/cmov/libc.so.6(+0x6af71)[0xb7639f71]
/lib/i686/cmov/libc.so.6(+0x6c7c8)[0xb763b7c8]
/lib/i686/cmov/libc.so.6(cfree+0x6d)[0xb763e8ad]
./assignment[0x8048779]
/lib/i686/cmov/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xe6)[0xb75e5ca6]
./assignment[0x80484d1]
======= Memory map: ========
08048000-08049000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 16674      /home/os/Documents/assignment
08049000-0804a000 rw-p 00000000 08:01 16674      /home/os/Documents/assignment
09379000-0939a000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0          [heap]
b7400000-b7421000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
b7421000-b7500000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0
b75a0000-b75bd000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 245763     /lib/libgcc_s.so.1
b75bd000-b75be000 rw-p 0001c000 08:01 245763     /lib/libgcc_s.so.1
b75ce000-b75cf000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
b75cf000-b770f000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 267347     /lib/i686/cmov/libc-2.11.3.so
b770f000-b7710000 ---p 00140000 08:01 267347     /lib/i686/cmov/libc-2.11.3.so
b7710000-b7712000 r--p 00140000 08:01 267347     /lib/i686/cmov/libc-2.11.3.so
b7712000-b7713000 rw-p 00142000 08:01 267347     /lib/i686/cmov/libc-2.11.3.so
b7713000-b7716000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
b7723000-b7728000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
b7728000-b7729000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0          [vdso]
b7729000-b7744000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 250358     /lib/ld-2.11.3.so
b7744000-b7745000 r--p 0001b000 08:01 250358     /lib/ld-2.11.3.so
b7745000-b7746000 rw-p 0001c000 08:01 250358     /lib/ld-2.11.3.so
bfe1d000-bfe32000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0          [stack]
^C
os@debian:~/Documents$


#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h> 
//Source: "geeksforgeeks.org/c-program-bubble-sort-linked-list/"
//Source: "geeksforgeeks.org/fgetc-fputc-c/"
struct Node 
{
    int value;
    struct Node* next;

} Node;

//defining an insert that will put an integer into the linked list
void insert(struct Node *);

//defining a head pointer variable
struct Node* head = NULL;

void main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    //checking to see if the arguments passed were 3
    if(argc != 3) 
    {
        printf("Please run as %s [filename]\n", argv[1]);
        return; 
    }

    FILE *fp; 
    //checking if the input file is readable
    if(!(fp = fopen(argv[1], "r")))
    {
        printf("filename %s does not exist", argv[1]);
        return;
    }

    //allocating memory to line
    struct Node * line = (struct Node*) malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    printf("made it here \n");
    //ensuring the dynamic memory management allocated the memory to line
    if(line == NULL) 
    {
        printf("Cannot do dynamic memory management\n");
        return; 
    }
    //printf("file in content is %s: \n", argv[1]);
    //loop through the file and and put the information into the list 
    while(fscanf(fp, "%d", &(line->value)) != EOF)
    {
        line -> next = NULL;
        insert(line); 
        line = (struct Node*) malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
        if(line == NULL) 
        {   
            printf("No more space to allocate for dynamic memory                management\n"); 
            return;
        }
        printf("%d", line->value);  
    }
    free(line);

    //while(fscanf(fp, "%d", &(line->value)) != EOF) 
    //{
    //  printf("%d", line->value); 
    //}
    fclose(fp); 
    printf("Content is in the linked list\n"); 
    //////////////////////////////////////////
    FILE *f;    
    //checking if the output file is valid
    if(!(f = fopen(argv[2], "w")))
    {
        printf("file %s not valid \n", argv[2]);
        return;
    }

    //print the sorted list to the output file and move the pointer to the next         //node.

    while(head != NULL) 
    {
        line = head;
        head = head->next;  
        fprintf(f, "%d ", line->value); 
        free(line); 
    }
    printf("Content is in %s [filename] as follows: \n", argv[2]);
    fclose(f); 
}

void insert(struct Node * element)
{
    struct Node * temp = head; 
    struct Node * pretemp = NULL; 

    while(temp != NULL && temp->value < element->value) 
    {
        pretemp = temp; 
        temp = temp->next;
    }
    if(pretemp == NULL) 
    {
        element->next = head;
        head = element; 
    }
    else
    {
        pretemp->next = element;
        element->next = temp; 
    }
}
```

Comment: The `free(line)` immediately after your `fscanf` loop looks very suspicious.

Comment: @NateEldredge If you're referring to the free after the while-loop, it's supposed to be there. The OP allocates prior to the loop. With each iteration they append the allocated item to their list, then allocate a new one, and continue on. When the loop finally exists there is one additional `line` that was overallocated and needs to be freed. Not the most ideal design, but it is nonetheless sound.The `printf("%d", line->value);` at the bottom of that loop, however, is completely pointless, and technically invokes UB (the `value` member of the new allocation was never set).

Comment: Thank you, I removed the printf line, but the problem still persists.

Comment: I downloaded and ran your program. I'm unable to reproduce your issue. But, changing `while(fscanf(fp, "%d", &(line->value)) != EOF)` to `while(fscanf(fp, "%d", &(line->value)) == 1)` may help. Also, don't cast `malloc`. And, `main` is type `int` so do `return 1` and add a `return 0` at the bottom.

Comment: I should've mentioned I am running this on a VM in the debian OS. This might be why the issue was unable to be reproduced. Also, can you specify more detail about what I did wrong using malloc?

Answer (score 0):

I was compiling and running the code using the name of the file. Instead of running the file as ./a.out.